# Is it possible to use xslt to style a crosstab view?

Tags: xml, xslt, pivot-table, crosstab

I have an xml document that looks something like this:

```
<units>
    <unit>
       <year></year>
       <month></month>
       <qty></qty>
    </unit>
</units>
```

I want to create a crosstab view of this data in html with each row represented by a year, each column represented by a month, and each value containing the sum of the qty's for the specific year/month. Something a little like this:

```
      Jan  Feb   Mar   Apr.... etc
2010  345    0    12     0
2011    1   23   344     0
2012   99    1    23     0.... etc
```

My primary question is this: is crosstab even possible with xslt?

My follow-up question would be can you point an xslt newbie, such as myself, in the right direction to get started trying to make this work?

SAMPLE DATA:

```
<units>
    <unit>
        <year>2010</year>
        <month>9</month>
        <qty>13320</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2010</year>
        <month>9</month>
        <qty>2445</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2010</year>
        <month>10</month>
        <qty>8949</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2010</year>
        <month>10</month>
        <qty>13650</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2010</year>
        <month>11</month>
        <qty>4091</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2010</year>
        <month>11</month>
        <qty>6600</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2010</year>
        <month>12</month>
        <qty>686</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2010</year>
        <month>12</month>
        <qty>678</qty>
    </unit>

    <unit>
        <year>2011</year>
        <month>1</month>
        <qty>1234</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2011</year>
        <month>1</month>
        <qty>12345</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
         <year>2011</year>
        <month>2</month>
        <qty>4500</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2011</year>
        <month>2</month>
        <qty>999</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2011</year>
        <month>3</month>
        <qty>166</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
         <year>2011</year>
        <month>3</month>
        <qty>456666</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2011</year>
        <month>4</month>
        <qty>41113</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2011</year>
        <month>4</month>
        <qty>1150</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2011</year>
        <month>5</month>
        <qty>4150</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2011</year>
        <month>5</month>
        <qty>491</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2011</year>
        <month>6</month>
        <qty>11250</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2011</year>
        <month>6</month>
        <qty>3400</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
         <year>2011</year>
        <month>7</month>
        <qty>485</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2011</year>
        <month>7</month>
        <qty>90</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2011</year>
        <month>8</month>
        <qty>1606</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
         <year>2011</year>
        <month>8</month>
        <qty>202000</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2011</year>
        <month>9</month>
        <qty>45333</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2011</year>
        <month>9</month>
        <qty>13650</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2011</year>
        <month>10</month>
        <qty>4050</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2011</year>
        <month>10</month>
        <qty>431</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2011</year>
        <month>11</month>
        <qty>45713</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2011</year>
        <month>11</month>
        <qty>13690</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2011</year>
        <month>12</month>
        <qty>4050</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2011</year>
        <month>12</month>
        <qty>431</qty>
    </unit>

    <unit>
        <year>2012</year>
        <month>1</month>
        <qty>2500</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2012</year>
        <month>1</month>
        <qty>34100</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2012</year>
        <month>2</month>
        <qty>400</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2012</year>
        <month>2</month>
        <qty>99</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2012</year>
        <month>3</month>
        <qty>1606</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2012</year>
        <month>3</month>
        <qty>202000</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2012</year>
        <month>4</month>
        <qty>53773</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2012</year>
        <month>4</month>
        <qty>13650</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2012</year>
        <month>5</month>
        <qty>4150</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2012</year>
        <month>5</month>
        <qty>4231</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2012</year>
        <month>6</month>
        <qty>278</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2012</year>
        <month>6</month>
        <qty>6100</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2012</year>
        <month>7</month>
        <qty>406</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
        <year>2012</year>
        <month>7</month>
        <qty>95</qty>
    </unit>

</units>
```

Comment: What version of XSLT? 1.0? or 2.0?

Comment: How about some sample data with actual numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is an XSLT 1.0 solution** (there might be some work needed to make the numbers align properly):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:key name="kUnitByY" match="unit" use="year"/>
 <xsl:key name="kUnitByYM" match="unit" use="concat(year,'|',month)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
<xsl:text>      Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "unit[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kUnitByY',year)[1])]">
    <xsl:sort select="year" data-type="number"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="unit">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;',year,'  ')"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vCur" select="."/>

  <xsl:for-each select="(//node()|//namespace::*)[not(position() >12)]">
    <xsl:value-of select=
    "sum(key('kUnitByYM', concat($vCur/year,'|',position()))/qty)"/>
    <xsl:text>    </xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (none was provided !!!):

2010
       2
       3
    
    
       2010
       3
       44
    
    
       2010
       9
       44
    
    
       2011
       1
       5
    
    
       2011
       3
       11
    
    
       2011
       6
       11
    
    
       2011
       4
       15

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
      Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
2010  0    3    44    0    0    0    0    0    44    0    0    0    
2011  5    0    11    15    0    11    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: @Dimitire , Nice efficient solution. Just one minor thing: The sort order for years should be ascending.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin, The OP doesn't state the order -- Just now I looked at his wanted result and see the order really is ascending -- quite counter-intuitive. Thanks, I will fix this now.

Comment: Almost there! This solution works except for some reason all the marches (month=3), all the junes (month=6), and all the septembers (month =9) are returning 0. The other months are accurately summing.

Comment: @PriceJones, I always post verified, working solutions -- actually copying/pasting the actual transformation result into the answer. This transformation produces the same result when run with all 9 XSLT processors I am working with. The reason you are getting a different result is most likely that: 1. You have changed the XSLT code. 2. You have changed the XML document. 3. Both 1. and 2.; 4. You are using a non-compliant/buggy XSLT processor.

Comment: @Dimitire, You are correct. My xslt processor is buggy. I just double checked it in ie9. It worked great. Thanks Dimitre. I appreciate your help on this problem!

Comment: @PriceJones, I edited this answer and provided a new XML document that has data for allthree months for which you claim that zero results are produced. The actual result as shown has the right numbers for all months.

Comment: @PriceJones, You are welcome. Which XSLT processor is it? It would be good to report the bug to the vendor.

Answer (score 1):

## XSLT 1.0 Solution

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:key name="row" match="unit" use="year" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:text>     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec&#x0A;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*/unit[
    generate-id() = generate-id( key('row',year)[1])]">
      <xsl:sort select="year" data-type="number" />
  </xsl:apply-templates>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="unit">
  <xsl:variable name="year" select="year" />
  <xsl:value-of select="concat($year,' ')" />
  <xsl:for-each select="((/)//@*|(/)//node())[position() &lt; 13]">
    <xsl:variable name="month-num" select="position()" />
    <xsl:variable name="sum" select="sum(/*/unit[year=$year][month=$month-num]/qty)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring('   ',1,3 - string-length($sum)),$sum,' ')" />
  </xsl:for-each>  
  <xsl:value-of select="'&#x0A;'" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...will take input like this...

```
<units>
    <unit>
       <year>2010</year>
       <month>2</month>
       <qty>3</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
       <year>2010</year>
       <month>3</month>
       <qty>44</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
       <year>2011</year>
       <month>1</month>
       <qty>5</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
       <year>2011</year>
       <month>3</month>
       <qty>11</qty>
    </unit>
    <unit>
       <year>2011</year>
       <month>4</month>
       <qty>15</qty>
    </unit>
</units>
```

... and produce text like this...

```
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2010   0   3  44   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
2011   5   0  11  15   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

---

## XSLT 2.0 Solution

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
       Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
  <xsl:for-each-group select="*/unit" group-by="year">
    <xsl:sort select="year" data-type="number" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(current-grouping-key(),' ')" />  
      <xsl:value-of select="        
          (string-join(
          for $month-num in 1 to 12 return
                for $sum in sum(current-group()/qty) return
                  concat(substring('   ',1,3 - string-length($sum)),$sum),
          ' '), '&#x0A;')" />
 </xsl:for-each-group>    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

## Update 1

Added line termination correction suggested by Dimitre.

---

## Update 2

Removed the leading zeros in output, but retaining column alignment.

---

## Caveats

1. The XSLT 1.0 solution only works when the maximum sum is less than 1000. Adjust accordingly if not.
2. Dimitre's solution of leveraging off the the key rather than re-computing '/*/unit[year=$year][month=$month-num]' is superior. Perhaps the optimal solution would be to use his key() style solution for computing sums, but fragments of my code for non-leading zero column alignment.

Comment: I have to apologize. I am using version 1.0. Your code seems to work fine, except for one issue. The sum function is returning only 0's. I cannot fathom why.

Comment: Would there be a reason why the predicates in the line "sum(/*/unit[year=$year][month=$month-num]/qty)" would fail? I think this is the problem. For some reason the variable is failing...

Comment: I tested it and it works fine for me. You did not post any test data. Can you post some test data (input document)?

Comment: Also note the perfect column alignment of the data cells. This relies upon the assumption that all sums will be less than 1000. The call to format-number() with pattern '000' is responsible for this.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin, Your solution seems to produce unwanted (one row only) output with the data I am using. Also, the numbers aren't exactly "perfect", because the OP's wantted result has no leading zeroes.

Comment: Dimitre: Yes, your right about the one row. I forgot to emit the LF character at the end of the line. Thanks for that catch. Will fix. I am going to think about how to get rid of the extraneous extra zeros in the numbers, but retain correct column alignment.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using the [`Muenchian Method`](http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2005/02/crosstabs_of_xm.html)